# Converting XML to Excel with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, excel-2010

```
<properties>
<entry key="type">exSafe:Nocontract</entry>
<entry key="aspects">cm:version,cm:title,cm:own,cm:author</entry>
<entry key="cm:creator">1122334455</entry>
<entry key="cm:autoVersion">true</entry>
<entry key="cm:title">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</entry>
<entry key="cm:modifier">1122334455</entry>
<entry key="cm:created">2013-07-28T08:30:51.000+01:00</entry>
<entry key="gwSafe:contractCustVend">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX999</entry>
</properties>
```

I have following XML file and I would like to convert them into Excel file through PowerShell, Can anyone help me, please?

Here is what I have so far:

```
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content "k1.xml" 
#export xml as csv
$inputFile.Sites.ChildNodes | Export-Csv "k1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8
```

Comment: SO is NOT a script writing service. Own effort is required to get help. Can you provide us with a code sample of what you have already tried? A tip I can give to to script this yourself : to parse an XML you can use the [xml] type in Powershell. To export to Excel you can hook up the Excel COM object. What I've also noticed : your XML sample is incomplete, the Properties element is not being closed.

Comment: First, I am new to Poweshell and second, I post my question once I failed to do so with my own script. Thanks anyways! `[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content "k1.xml"
#export xml as csv
$inputFile.Sites.ChildNodes | Export-Csv "k1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8` Even I have tried to convert the XML file into CSV, but that did not work too.

Comment: Welcome to the site Tuhin, I have updated your question for you to include your code snippet, in future always include that so we can see what you have attempted/failed on - this will help you become better and learn other ways of coding in PowerShell. You can refer to this site for how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I've written a small sample to get you started. This contains the basic logic.
I didn't include the code to add the headers (since this is quite trivial to accomplish and this also leaves something to do yourself)

```
[xml]$XML = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<entry key="type">exSafe:Nocontract</entry>
<entry key="aspects">cm:version,cm:title,cm:own,cm:author</entry>
<entry key="cm:creator">1122334455</entry>
<entry key="cm:autoVersion">true</entry>
<entry key="cm:title">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</entry>
<entry key="cm:modifier">1122334455</entry>
<entry key="cm:created">2013-07-28T08:30:51.000+01:00</entry>
<entry key="gwSafe:contractCustVend">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX999</entry>
</properties>
'@

## Create Excel COM Object
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# Set the sheet to visible so you can actually see it (for testing purposes)
$excel.Visible = $true
# Create a workbook
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
# Get sheet 1
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
# Set a counter
$x = 1;
# here we loop through the XML data and add this to the excel sheet
foreach ($entry in $XML.properties.entry)
    {
        $sheet.Cells.Item($x,1) = $entry.Key
        $sheet.Cells.Item($x,2) = $entry.'#text'
        $x++
    }
```